# Is there a way to convert integers in a column to character in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a data frame which has different clinical variables for patients who either had a heart failure or not?

I have a column as gender with values 0 and 1, 0 corresponding to females and 1 corresponding to males?

My question is

How can I get my data frame column from this

```
gender 
1
1
0
1
0
0
```

to this...

```
gender
Female 
Male 
Male
Female 
Male 
Female 
Female
```

Is there a way to convert the integers 0, 1 to text "Female" and "Male"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass a replacement vector after converting to index by adding 1 to it.  In `R`, the indexing starts from 1, and thus by adding 1 to 0, 1, the values are changed to 1 and 2 respectively which can be used as a position index for replacement

```
df1$gender <- c("Female", "Male")[df1$gender + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse()` could work like this:

```
df <- data.frame(gender = c(1,0,1,0,3))

df$gender2 <- ifelse(df$gender == 1, "Male", "Female")
df
#>   gender gender2
#> 1      1    Male
#> 2      0  Female
#> 3      1    Male
#> 4      0  Female
#> 5      3  Female
```

You can also stack multiple conditions:

```
df$gender3 <- ifelse(df$gender == 1, "Male", 
                     ifelse(df$gender == 0, "Female", NA))
df
#>   gender gender2 gender3
#> 1      1    Male    Male
#> 2      0  Female  Female
#> 3      1    Male    Male
#> 4      0  Female  Female
#> 5      3  Female    <NA>
```